# Lambda expression to return zero if null

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-objects

in my WPF application i used to add controls dynamically to a Canvas. The name format of the control is "Control_UniqueValue".

i.e., if i add first control to the canvas, then the name will be "Control_1" and the next will be "Control_2" etc...

my requirement is to get the max value of the added controls

i used the following statement for that

```
string maxId = (string)canvas1.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>().ToList().Max(x => (x.Name.Substring(x.Name.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)));
```

but the problem here is

1. need to return the value as int
2. if the canvas contains no controls it will raise error (tried using `Nullable` type, but failed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int  maxId = canvas1.Children
    .Cast<FrameworkElement>()
    .Select(e => int.Parse(e.Name.Substring(e.Name.LastIndexOf('_'))))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Max();
```

This should return 0 instead of throwing an exception if there are no elements in the sequence. Also, the call to `ToList` in your code is not required. This will still throw an exception if any of the control names are not in the expected format.

Answer (score 4):

To get an integer, you might use the `int.Parse` method. You don't have to call `ToList()`.

There is no error checking, so your controls have to named regarding to your rule `name_id`.

You can use the `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method to provide a default value, if the sequence is empty:

```
int maxId = canvas1.Children
             .Cast<FrameworkElement>()
             .DefaultIfEmpty(new FrameworkElement() { Name = "Control_0" })
             .Max(x => (int.Parse(x.Name.Split('_')[1]) + 1)));
```

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You have to provide an instance of the FrameworkElement class as default value for the empty list of cause.

Answer (score 3):

Since Max() requires at least one element in its sequence you either have to

- catch the exception and set max to zero
- check the length before calling Max(). *I'd recommend this*

While it is possible to write the logic in one long query expression, I'd recommend you break it up a bit to improve readability. Create a method that returns the integer part of a child control's name:

```
private int NumberFromElementName(string name)
{
    // Or search for the last '_' using name.LastIndexOf()
    var numString = name.Substring("Control_".Length);
    return Int32.Parse(numString);
}
```

Then do the query in two steps to allow you to look at the length of the returned sequence. Notice I convert it to an array to avoid having to run the query twice. I'm also using the [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method so that it works even if the canvas has a child which isn't of type FrameworkElement.

```
var children = canvas1.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().ToArray();
int max = 0;
if (children.Length > 0)
    max = children.Max(x => NumberFromElementName(x.Name));
string nextChildName = String.Format ("Control_{0}", max + 1);
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @Jan in his answer, you can avoid splitting the query in two parts by using the [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) before the Max call in the query.

Answer (score 0):

got the final answer

```
int maxId = canvas1.Children .Cast<FrameworkElement>() .Select(e => int.Parse(e.Name.Substring(e.Name.LastIndexOf('_')+ 1))) .DefaultIfEmpty() .Max(x => x + 1);
```

Thanks Jan & Lee